# `NullPointerException` is encountered while fetching data

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jpa

So ,  I am saving a list using spring mvc and jpa as follows:

```
myRepository.save(myObjList);
```

A job is running side by side and fetching the data from the table.
Now for first few records(4-5) I am getting `NullPointerException` whereas the data is present as well is it is running fine for rest of the records.

The data where I am getting NPE is for the object where `@OneToMany` or `@ManyToMany` annotation is present.

Surprisingly the same code is working fine for the same data after 4-5 records.

Am I missing any configuration?

Comment: What is your Strategy for loading `@OneToMany`? `Lazy` or `Eager`?

Comment: @PawełGłowacz Job is a different application.So I am deep loading the Mappings.Sample Code used : inside foreach loop : if(myObj.getXXX()!=null)
     myObj.getXXX().size();

Comment: @PawełGłowacz anything further info required?

Comment: Throw job code and entities code in your question. I would like to see also full stack trace.

Comment: Nothing other than NPE is in logger.If I debug the code with same data.Its executes fine whereas when I  deploy the jar file on server , it thows NPE for a record.Is it something like data not completely loaded or dont know.But data is definately there in DB :( @PawełGłowacz

Comment: It is specific record or random one ?

Comment: For now im guessing. Please provide as much information/code as possible because now not only me but propably others are blind. Please provide: **1.** What framework/libs are you using. **2.** Provide codes for that questions: your entities, your `job code`. More detailed your question will be then we can figure out what is going on.

Comment: May be a silly question, but have you tried debugging with breakpoints?  It would be helpful to know exactly where your code is returning a null value.